# Model for 'Pattern to Pattern'?

Tags: deep-learning, scikit-learn, keras, lstm, sequential-pattern-mining

How to create a model that will generate a similar pattern/image?
And how sould I address it, if I only have 400 exmples after the augmentation.

**This is the kind of data I have (16X16)**
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,5,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,2,3,3,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,1,7,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,7,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,7,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

I tried to go for DL but I can't get my hand on an example.

Cheers :))